# function jquery call twice or doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I've a menu when I click on an item, it loads a page in a div "content". I tried two ways to do but I don't find a good issue.
First way: I've a jquery funcion Gallery() (it's to make a menu slider) that  I call in the page loaded but it call it every time the page is loaded so it doesn't work well.
Second way: this function is called in my page html "index.php" where is the div "content", it works only for a part because it can't define some variables (like `$('#gallery ul li.vizu').length`).
Please help! I don't know what to do!

```js
function Gallery() {

 var marge = 10;
 function showSlide(direction) {
  var SlideWidthP = $('#gallery ul li.active').prev().width();
  var SlideWidthN = $('#gallery ul li.active').width();
  left = ( direction == 1 ) ? "+=" + (SlideWidthN+marge) : "-=" + (SlideWidthP+marge);
  $('#gallery').stop( true, true ).animate({left: left}, 800);
  };
 
 $('.previous').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#gallery ul li').eq( 0 ).hasClass('active')){
   $('#gallery ul li').hasClass('active')
   }else{
   $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
   showSlide(1);
  }  
 });

 $('.next'). click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#gallery ul li').last().hasClass('active')){
   $('#gallery ul li').hasClass('active')
   }else{
   $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
   showSlide(-1);
  }
 });
 
 var VizuCount = $('#gallery ul li.vizu').length;
 var TextCount = $('#gallery ul li.text').length;
 var PlanCount = $('#gallery ul li.plan').length;
 var VizuWidth = 
  $('#gallery ul li.vizu').each(function(){
   $Vizuwidth=$('#gallery ul li.vizu').width()+marge;
   })
 var TextWidth = 
  $('#gallery ul li.text').each(function(){
   $Textwidth=$('#gallery ul li.text').width()+marge;
   })
 var PlanWidth = 
  $('#gallery ul li.plan').each(function(){
   $Planwidth=$('#gallery ul li.plan').width()+marge;
   })
 var VizuLenght= VizuCount*$Vizuwidth;
 var TextLenght= TextCount*$Textwidth;
 var PlanLenght= PlanCount*$Planwidth;
 
 $('#boutons .icoImage').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#gallery').animate({left:0},800);
  $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#gallery ul li.vizu').first().addClass('active');
 });
 $('#boutons .icoTexte').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#gallery').animate({left:-VizuLenght},800);
  $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#gallery ul li.text').first().addClass('active');
 }); 
 $('#boutons .icoPlan').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#gallery').animate({left:-(VizuLenght+TextLenght)},800);
  $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#gallery ul li.plan').first().addClass('active');
 }); 
 
 
}
function Menu2(){
 var marge = 10;
 var VizuCount = $('#gallery ul li.vizu').length;
 var TextCount = $('#gallery ul li.text').length;
 var PlanCount = $('#gallery ul li.plan').length;
 var VizuWidth = 
  $('#gallery ul li.vizu').each(function(){
   $Vizuwidth=$('#gallery ul li.vizu').width()+marge;
   })
 var TextWidth = 
  $('#gallery ul li.text').each(function(){
   $Textwidth=$('#gallery ul li.text').width()+marge;
   })
 var PlanWidth = 
  $('#gallery ul li.plan').each(function(){
   $Planwidth=$('#gallery ul li.plan').width()+marge;
   })
 var VizuLenght= VizuCount*$Vizuwidth;
 var TextLenght= TextCount*$Textwidth;
 var PlanLenght= PlanCount*$Planwidth;
 
 $('#boutons .icoImage').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#gallery').animate({left:0},800);
  $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#gallery ul li.vizu').first().addClass('active');
 });
 $('#boutons .icoTexte').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#gallery').animate({left:-VizuLenght},800);
  $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#gallery ul li.text').first().addClass('active');
 }); 
 $('#boutons .icoPlan').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#gallery').animate({left:-(VizuLenght+TextLenght)},800);
  $('#gallery ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#gallery ul li.plan').first().addClass('active');
 }); 
}
//loadPage
function loadPage(url){ 
 $('#content').load(url,Loader); 
 };
Loader =
 function(){
  if($('#gallery').length){
       $('#menu2').show();
   $('#gallery ul li').first().addClass('active');
   Gallery(); //here it called for the First Way
   }else{
   $('#menu2').hide();
   }
   
 };
```

```html
<!--Page INDEX.PHP!-->
<body onload=loadPage('<?=WEBROOT;?>page/<?=$accueil['nicename']?>')>

<div id="header" class="col-12">
</div><!--header-->
<div id="navigation" class="col-3">
<div id="logo">
<table>
<td>
<a href="index.php">
  <img src="img/logo.png"/> </a></td>
  </table>
</div><!--logo-->
<div id="mainmenu" class="col-2">
<?php foreach($menu as $menuitem):?>
    <ul class="menu">
    
     <li> <a href="Javascript:loadPage('<?=WEBROOT;?>page/<?=$menuitem['wnicename']?>');"><?=$menuitem['name']?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sousmenu">
                <?php 
    foreach($sousmenu as $sousmenuitem):
      if ($sousmenuitem['id_parent']== $menuitem['id']){
       ?>
     <li>
     <a href="Javascript:loadPage('<?=WEBROOT; ?>page/<?=$sousmenuitem['wnicename'] ;?>');"><?=$sousmenuitem['name']?></a></li>
     <?php }
                          endforeach; ?>
                       </ul>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!--mainmenu-->
</div><!--navigation-->
<div id="menu2">
  <div id="nomProj">      
         <?php //echo $_SESSION['worksname']?>
        </div><!--nomProj-->
     <div id="boutons">
      <a class="icoImage" href="#" title="Visuels"></a>
            <a class="icoTexte" href="#" title="Description"></a>
            <a class="icoPlan" href="#" title="Plans"></a>
     <div id="fleches">
        <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="next"></a>
    </div><!--fleches-->
    </div><!--boutons-->
 </div><!--menu2-->
 

<div id="content" class="col-12">

</div><!--content-->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/mainmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  if($('#gallery')){Gallery()};
</script><!--here it called for the Second Way
  
<!--Page LOADED!-->
<?php                                        
if ($work['gallery']==1){
 echo '<div id="gallery"><ul>';
 foreach($vizu as $v):
  echo '<li class="vizu"><img src="' . WEBROOT2 .'img/works/'. $v['name']. '" height="500px"></li>';
  endforeach;
 foreach($texte as $t):
  echo '<li class="text"><img src="' . WEBROOT2 .'img/works/'. $t['name']. '" height="500px"></li>';
  endforeach;
 foreach($plan as $p):
  echo '<li class="plan"><img src="' . WEBROOT2 .'img/works/'. $p['name']. '" height="500px"></li>';
  endforeach;;
 echo "</ul></div>";
 }else{
 echo '<div id="page">'.$work['content'].'<div>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Smith..
What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: My problem is that I've a function which doesn't work well. This function is used for a navigation with a second menu ("menu2") in pages "gallery" which are loaded in a div "content" in my page "index". In the first case the function is called in the load function but the result is that the function piles up because it's called every time the menu-item is clicked.

Comment: In the second case, The function is called in my "index" page. Here, the function works for only a part of the code (button "prev" and button "next" but not for buttons "ico..."). So the navigation has problems everytime but not the same. Thnaks for you help!